# Images in sqlite huge

Tags: android, image, sqlite

I have 5 Mb worth of images that I want to put into an sqlite db, in blob fields.
After the insertion, the db is around 50Mb.

This is how I get the `byte[]`:

```
private static byte[] getByteArrayFromFileName(String filename) {
    int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(filename, "raw", context.getPackageName());
    ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), id).compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, blob);
    return blob.toByteArray();
}
```

This is how I insert them into the db:

```
public void createImage(SQLiteDatabase database, Image image) throws DbException {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ImageTable.DATA, image.data);
    values.put(ImageTable.TYPE_ID, image.type.getValue());
    values.put(ImageTable.LEVELID, image.levelId);
    values.put(ImageTable.ID, image.id);

    if (database.replace(ImageTable.TABLE_NAME, null, values) == -1) {
        throw new DbException("createImage insertion error");
    }
}
```

What am I screwing up? :)

edit: the problem was, I should not be putting bitmaps into the database, but just the raw (compressed in jpeg format)files. So for reference, here is a correct way of getting a byte[] from a bitmap file, so it's still small in size:

```
private static byte[] getByteArrayFromRawByFileName(Context context, String filename) throws IOException {
        int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(filename, "raw", context.getPackageName());
        InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(id);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int bytesRead;
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        while ((bytesRead = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }
```

Comment: you shouldn't store images as blobs in databases. fact.

Comment: anyway, what's the problem, exactly? the 10x size increase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the problem is you are using `JPEG` images as source but before insertion you encoding them to `PNG` and that's the reason of 10x grow I believe. Your `getByteArrayFromFileName`() is also a fail cuz since you have a file you could read it as `byteArray` without `BitmapFactory` involving

Comment: that's almost the answer...I was reading them in as bitmap, and not just as files, that's why the size increased :)

Answer (score 0):

Storing images as a blob in your database may not be such a good idea. A couple reasons are...

- On Android, your database files are stored in the phone's internal storage, not the SD card. Since the phone's internal storage may be quite limited, it's always a good idea to store large stuff on the SD card. Although, this argument may be invalid on newer devices that do not allow for expanded storage.
- If the user decided to uninstall your app, the images also go with it.

I would suggest saving the images to the SD card, and  store the file path in the database.

Comment: the whole point is to prevent the user from accessing the images easily. :)